# Linux links (shortcuts) in exfat filesystem

Tags: linux, exfat

Is it possible to create a link in an exfat partition in linux? I wanted to create a link to a file deep in some folders and "ln -s" doesn't work because exfat doesn't support symlinks. changing the filesystem is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Exfat does not support symlinks. You cannot create one.

Comment: I don't need a symlink. windows can create shortcuts in exfat, is there any other way in linux to create a link in linux other than symlinks?

Comment: A symlink and shortcuts are entirely different beast to a symlink. A symlink is a construct of a filesystem, while a shortcut is a file interpreted by the GUI.

Comment: a Windows shortcut is like a Linux's .desktop file. The shortcut file just contains the path and doesn't point to anything and can exist even if the source file has been deleted

Comment: See also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/628495/114401) and [here](https://www.scivision.dev/rsync-to-exfat-drive/) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=rsync+best+settigs+syncing+to+exfat&oq=rsync+best+settigs+syncing+to+exfat&aqs=chrome..69i57.6539j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround:

```
touch /shallow/file
sudo mount --bind /deep/into/directory/tree/file /shallow/file
```

Disadvantages:

- Needs `sudo`.
- Works on OS level, not on filesystem level. After every reboot you need to repeat `mount` to use this "link"; or [edit your `/etc/fstab`](https://serverfault.com/a/613184) to make this solution permanent.

Comment: you can add mount to the nopasswd sudo list and define mount as an alias to `sudo mount`. Now you don't need any password for mounting

Comment: @phuclv this will effectively provide everybody with root rights, as mount is an unsafe operation - you can bind-mount something you shouldn't have accessed, override uid/gid, do other nasty things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't appear to have any problems creating a symlink with `ln -s` on my exFAT partition running Ubunutu Server 20.04

```bsh
mdkir foo
cd foo
echo hi > bar
ln -s bar baz
echo ho > baz
```

`cat bar`

```
ho
```

`ls -l`

```bsh
-rwxrwxr-x  1 x x    3 Apr 11 13:13 bar*
lrwxrwxr-x  1 x x    3 Apr 11 13:13 baz -> bar*
```

Comment: `ln: failed to create symbolic link 'baz': Function not implemented`

Comment: @grabantot my guess is it depends on ntfs-3g, I did this running stock Ubuntu 20.04 server. Looking at ntfs-3g there appears to be an implementation for symlinks and junctions https://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/junctions.html
Under which circumstances did it fail for you?

Comment: It failed for `exFAT` on manjaro (don't have it at hand, can't get more details). You were talking about `exFAT` in the response, but in the comment you mention `ntfs-3g` - is there a mistake?

Comment: @grabantot ah, yes, my bad. I confused myself. In Ubuntu 20.04 there should be support for `exFat` in the kernel. I'll try and get some more details on my system. Might be helpful for others if you could contribute your Manjaro/kernel version

Comment: It is working on MacOS Monterey.

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts:

- You could try using a hard link, though I'm not sure it'll work.
- You could create the symlink on a non exfat drive and have the target point to a file on the exfat drive, since soft links can cross drive boundaries.
- If you have no other drive to implement the above, you could even create a small ext4fs system using "mke2fs", loop mounting it, and then linking from it to the exfat system.
- If you create a shortcut in Windows, Linux *may* see it as a '.lnk' file, but you won't be able to use it like a symbolic link.

Comment: according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee681827(v=vs.85).aspx) exFAT supports neither softlink or hardlink

Comment: Linux will always see the *.lnk file as it's just a normal file like any other files. It's completely different from softlink or hardlink in Windows